# Generate Aztec triangle of size n automatically？

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry, lattices

In the paper titled "[Perfect Matchings of Cellular Graphs](https://www.emis.de/journals/JACO/Volume5_2/m24482170h4470l6.fulltext.pdf)" by Mihai Ciucu, the Aztec triangle of size `n (n= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)` is equivalent to a triangular grid of `n1` squares `(n1 = 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ...)` .

See the following example:
[image]

Is there a automatical way to generate such patterns? (additionally, is it possiable to get the connected points into a list?)

Also are there some general method to generate [Aztec diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_diamond) of order `n` (not just triangle)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

```
aztecGraph[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := NearestNeighborGraph[
  SortBy[Last] @ DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten[#, 2]& @
   Table[{i, - j} + # & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], {j, 0, n - 1}, {i, -j, j}], opts]
```

***Examples:***

```
aztecGraph[9, ImageSize -> 1 -> 30]
```

[image]

```
aztecGraph[5, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, GraphStyle -> "IndexLabeled"]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Partition[aztecGraph[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> 30] & /@ Range[6], 3], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
aztecRect[n_] := Rectangle /@ 
    (Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[{#, -#2[[1]]}] &, Range[-#, #] &@Range[0, n - 1]]);
```

***Examples:***

```
Grid[Partition[Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Red], aztecRect @ #}, 
     ImageSize -> 1 -> 20] & /@ Range[6], 3],
   Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

We can get a `Graph`  object from `aztecRect` using `DiscretizeGraphics` + `MeshCoordinates` + `NearestNeighborGraph`:

```
rectsToGraph = NearestNeighborGraph @* MeshCoordinates @* 
   DiscretizeGraphics @* Graphics @* aztecRect;

rectsToGraph @ 5
```

[image]

Comment: nice, thank you! can I then also use something like `List @@@ EdgeList[triangleGridGraph[2]]` to get the paried vertices?

Comment: @Xuemei, please see the update.

Comment: wow, thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

A combination of `ArrayMesh[]` and `MeshConnectivityGraph[]` with `DiamondMatrix[]` works well, if vertex indexing is not something you're concerned with:

```
Table[MeshConnectivityGraph[ArrayMesh[Take[DiamondMatrix[n - 1], n]]], {n, 4}]
```

[image: Aztec triangle graphs]

The Aztec diamond can also be generated with similar code (spot the difference!):

```
Table[MeshConnectivityGraph[ArrayMesh[DiamondMatrix[n, 2 n]]], {n, 5}]
```

[image: Aztec triangle graphs]

Comment: that is a interesting combination, thank you!